# How the proxy instance pass itself to the InvocationHandler?

Tags: java, proxy-classes

here is the method signature from the Proxy class:

```
Object java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(ClassLoader loader, Class<?>[] interfaces, InvocationHandler h) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

I check the source code of the newProxyInstance in the Proxy Class, i couldn't find where the proxy object pass itself to the InvocationHandler method

```
public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
throws Throwable;
```

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're on the hook to provide the reference through the usual means.  One common pattern is to create a final variable to reference the target and pass an anonymous implementation of `InvocationTargetHandler` to the `Proxy.newProxyInstance` method like so:

```
final Object myObject = /*initialize the proxy target*/;
final Object proxy = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    classLoader,
    new Class[] { /*your interface(s)*/ }, 
    new InvocationTargetHandler() {
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
            return method.invoke(myObject, args);
        }
});
```

This example is the most pointless proxy in the world because it patches all method calls through without doing anything, but you can fill in the `InvocationTargetHandler` with all sorts of fun stuff.

Sometimes the API feels a little bit klunky because the proxied object doesn't form part of the contract, but the JDK authors wanted to provide the possibility for the proxy class to exist without a backing concrete implementation.  It's quite useful that they did it that way...mock objects in your unit tests are a great of example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, my question not how to pass a proxy obj to the InvocationTargetHandler, my question is how the proxy got passed in the design? hence when i call proxy.getClass().getName() from invoke method, i got the same instance class name of my proxy.

Comment: @skystar7 no problem!  so if i understand correctly now, you're asking about the byte-code that the JRE generates when you call `newProxyInstance`.  if you delve into the JRE code, you'll find a class called `sun.misc.ProxyGenerator`.  that guy generates byte code for each proxy class that creates stub methods to invoke your proxy handler.  within those stub methods, the `proxy` parameter is simply passed as `this`.